# make a \page and \subpage refer to method documentation in doxygen

Tags: c++, doxygen

I've inherited a C++ project from a colleague who has left the company. In this person's doxygen generated documentation, method documenations are referred to as subpages in the `Related Pages` tab. This was accomplished through a dummy `doxy.h` file. Something like this:

```
/*! \page fooPage foo Functions
 * 
 * - \subpage Copy
 */
```

Then `foo.h` would look like this:

```
/// <summary>   copy a bar </summary>
/// <param name="bar">  bar to copy </param>
/// <returns>copy of bar </returns>
int Copy(int bar);
```

When I run `doxygen -g` and `doxygen DoxyFile` on this setup I get the warning :

```
warning: unable to resolve reference to 'Copy' for \ref command
```

although the output also tells me that it has preprocessed and parsed `foo.h` without error or warning. Then, in the output, `foo Functions` is an active link under the `Related Pages` tab (as needed), but `Copy` is a dead link.

I can get the reference to `Copy` if I set `EXTRACT_ALL = YES` but, this isn't what is needed. With `EXTRACT_ALL`, the documentation for `Copy` is part of the contents of `foo.h` in `Files` and this is what the `Copy` link in `foo Functions` points to. I need to exclude the default `Files` tab from the documentation (mostly because I don't want doxy.h in there).

I can then get rid of the `Files` tab by generating and editing a layout file, but this isn't quite right either. The `Files` tab may be gone, but the documentation for `Copy` is still part of the documentation for `foo.h` rather than a stand-alone subpage. The documentation for `Copy` should be a true `\subpage` of `foo Functions`, not a link to its documentation in the generated description of `foo.h`. This is what was required originally and what my former colleague (somehow) accomplished and left behind.

Comment: The question is which version of doxyen did your former colleague use and which version of doxygen do you use?

Comment: I am using 1.8.18. I am pretty sure that my former colleague used the latest version at the time (December 2018).

Comment: So your former colleague will probably have used 1.8.14 (as 1.8.15 was released on December 27, 2018).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see with version 1.8.14 and 1.8.18 the link on the related pages is not dead.

From your input I only had to make 1 small change: sdding `/// \file` on top of the file `foo.h`.

Most likely the file `foo.h` is seen but not all information is noted.

The file `foo.h` would look like:

```
/// \file


/// <summary>   copy a bar </summary>
/// <param name="bar">  bar to copy </param>
/// <returns>copy of bar </returns>
int Copy(int bar);
```

**Edit 1**

I would rather use `\ref` here and not `\subpage`

**Edit 2**

> I need to exclude the default Files tab from the documentation

Doxygen has the possibility of steering, in a limited way, the "tabs". Issuing the command: `doxygen -l layout_file.xml` will create a `layout_file.xml` a and in the `Doxyfile` you can refer to this file as:

```
LAYOUT_FILE =layout_file.xml
```

In this file there is a line:

```
<tab type="files" visible="yes" title="">
```

changing this to

```
<tab type="files" visible="no" title="">
```

will remove the tab "files.

See also in the documentation: https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html#layout

Comment: This seems to have gotten rid of the need for EXTRACT_ALL = YES.

Comment: Is it all working now, or which point is still not working for you?

Comment: I added an edit to the answer regarding the "files tab"

Comment: Probably a good addition for completeness sake. I glossed over this detail.